# Product of two non-symmetric positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is positive semidefinite, a product of two nonsymmetric positive semidefinite matrices?

We know a matric $ A $‎ is positive semidefinite if ‎$ X‎^{T}AX‎\geq0‎‎ $‎ for any $ X‎\in ‎R‎^{n}‎‎ $‎.‎ I don't know if ‎$ A, B $ are nonsymmetric positive semidefinite matrices ‎and‎ ‎$ AB=BA $‎, then ‎$ AB $‎ is positive semidefinite. It is true if ‎$ A, B $ are symmetric positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: No. Consider $A=B=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you

Comment: PSD-ness is only meaningful for symmetric matrices.  I don't think this question is well-posed.